# VB.net Postgres Parameterized Query return no result

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I have this function in Visual Basic:

```vb
Private Function getpsqlsingle() As String
    sqlquery = "select username from web_user where email = '@email' and is_temporary='f'"
    Dim email As String = "test@test.com"

    Dim psqlconnection As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection("Server=" & signiantserver & ";port=5432;User Id=postgres;Database=DTM_DB")
    psqlconnection.Open()

    Dim psqlcommand As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(sqlquery, psqlconnection)
    psqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim param As NpgsqlParameter = New NpgsqlParameter("@email", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
    param.Value = email
    psqlcommand.Parameters.Add(param)

    Dim value = psqlcommand.ExecuteScalar

    psqlconnection.Close()
    Return value
End Function
```

I get no exception thrown yet i still do not get any result back. I do have this test@test.com in my DB and when I run it in pgAdmin4 
(`select username from web_user where email = 'test@test.com' and is_temporary='f'`) 
I do get a result back. Is there something I am not setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See if you get a result when you remove the single quotes in your query...
sqlquery = "select username from web_user where email = @email and is_temporary='f'"

Comment: I honestly have tried that before and gave me an error, but this time i tried it and it works. Tried it with multiple scenarios and works. Thanks.